In Android Studio, How Do You Display Files Saved Into An Internal Directory In A Column List?
I've developed a simple application in Android Studio that attempts to display files saved in an internal directory in a column list but it's not working.
Here is the code
            // File Directory
            val fileDirectory = File(filesDir, "File Directory")
            if (!fileDirectory.exists()) { fileDirectory.mkdirs() }

            // List of Files in File Directory
            val files = fileDirectory.listFiles()

            // Individual Files In File Directory
            var fileOne = File(fileDirectory, "File One.txt")
            var fileTwo = File(fileDirectory, "File Two.txt")
            var fileThree = File(fileDirectory, "File Three.txt")

            // Application Layout
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                
                // Displayed List of Files
                Column {
                    files?.forEach { file ->
                        Text(
                            text = file.name,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            fontSize = 30.sp) }  }

}

There are three files. They are all empty but that doesn't matter. I only want the name of each file to be shown but that's not happening. The screen is blank. I tried adding text to the files and used file.readText and it still showed nothing.
Android Studio tells me that all of the files are not being used despite the directory that they are located in is being used. How do I use the files?
Thanks for your time.

The way you are displaying the files is wrong.

@Composable
fun ShowFiles() {

    // Assume that files are getting from Device.
    // So put your code here accordingly.
    val files = listOf(
        "File One Text",
        "File Two Text",
        "File Three Text",
        "File Four Text",
    )

    LazyColumn {
        items(files) { item ->
            FileItem(item)
            HorizontalDivider(thickness = 0.5.dp)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FileItem(item: String) {
    Card(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = item)
    }
}

